# bad interpreter shell script

Tags: ubuntu, shell-script, gnuplot

Hi I'm trying to write a shell script for plotting with gnuplot however I keep running into the error: `bash: ./plot.sh: usr/bin/gnuplot: bad interpreter: No such file or directory`
I have checked the location 'usr/bin/gnuplot' and it definitely exists. I have also checked the permissions on the file and it is executable. I have also checked I can open gnuplot manually through the interpreter and encountered no problems here.

The following is my file:

```
#!usr/bin/gnuplot

reset
set terminal png
set output 'test.png'
set key inside left top vertical Right noreverse enhanced autotitles box linetype -1 linewidth 1.000
set samples 200, 200

set title "Arc trig"
set xlabel "x"
set ylabel "y"
set grid

plot [-3:5] asin(x),acos(x)
```

I'm running Ubuntu 12.10.

Any ideas would be much appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: typo in the shebang line, should be `#!/usr/bin/gnuplot`

Comment: Consider making sure you have permission to write the png file to the current directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Missed the "/" `#!/usr/bin/gnuplot`